I'm facing an issue while running my dynamic web project on tomcat server v.9
I am new to advance java, I have completed learning jdbc and now I am in servlets and I want to run my dynamic web project on tomact server v.9. even after configuring it in the server and when I am clicking run on server I see all the buttion geeting disabled. As shown in the below scrrenshots.
issue i am facing
I got stuck here and with out practing it I cant understand the upcoming topics to move further. Please, help me to fix this issue ?
dynamic web project code

Please do not add images for your code and error. Edit the question and add it formatted (surrounded by three backticks). Take a look on our How To Ask section

"configuring it in the server" is not enough of a description, and you should never, ever, put a copy of the Servlet or JSP APIs inside your project if you're properly getting them from a server runtime. Did anything show up in the Error Log view about this?

@JorgeCampos About which code exactly and about which error message exactly are you talking about? The question tells "i see all the buttion geeting diable.AS shown in the below scrrenshots". When should one add screenshots to a question, if not in such a case?

@howler Thanks for the note. I guess I read the question to fast. The first link mentions "... code" and title mentions "issue". Commented on muscle memory.

@JorgeCampos "No images of code" comments are always destructive, as they literally ask for information to be removed which then sometimes actually happen (see this recent example). Instead of telling what not to do, please ask for what is missing as precisely as possible.

Dynamic Web Projects are different than Java Project.You don't need to start a server and deploy your application to run it. However, you need to specify a class which contains a main() method. But it cannot run without JVM. The Dynamic Web Project cannot run without a server. There's a link provided by this answer to help you start learning a Dynamic Web Project.
